# Issue connecting to IIS process "Could not attach to the processs. Uncaught exception thrown by method called through reflection"

Tags: c#, debugging, iis, visual-studio-2019

All of a sudden Visual Studio 2019 stopped attaching to an IIS process. I started getting a message when trying to attach to the process that says "Could not attach to the process. Uncaught exception thrown by method called through Reflection"

I tried updating Visual Studio, I tried repairing Visual Studio, I tried reinstalling Visual Studio nothing is able to get this working.

I am however able to use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch, when I use this, it lets me attach to the process and run through a debug session.

One thing that is weird is after getting the error, I can close the "Attach to Process" window and see that Visual Studio is in a half debugging state where the red square is clickable and the Continue button is greyed out.

I can set a break point and hit it, but after that, the continue button, the step into, and step over buttons won't highlight and the keyboard shortcuts (F5, F10, F11) don't work.

Basically I'm stuck able to hit a break point, but not do anything further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix:
Delete the .vs folder. It's worth noting that Visual Studio 2022 also was throwing an Access Denied error when trying to attach to the process, this fix also resolved that issue.

Workaround:

Instead of clicking "Cancel" out of the Attach to Process window after getting the error message, just attach the debugger to the same process again. Then it'll work like a normal debugging session.